# key-value data structure to search key in O(1) and get Max value in O(1)

Tags: c++, boost, data-structures, stl, bimap

I need to implement a key-value data structure that search for a unique **key** in O(lgn) or O(1) AND get max **value** in O(1). I am thinking about

```
boost::bimap< unordered_set_of<key> ,multiset_of<value> >
```

Note that there is no duplicated key in my key-value data sets. However, two keys may have the same value. Therefore I used multiset to store values.

I need to insert/remove/update key-value pair frequently

How does it sounds ?

Comment: You might also consider a hash table in parallel with a max heap,  That's not really STL specific advice, but perhaps it's of use.

Comment: If you do not need to remove elements (you did not mention it the question) a simple class with an `std::map`/`std::unordered_map` and checking the max value at insert will do. The max heap solution by @acjohnson55 is for when you need to remove elements. The `bimap` does more than you want and therefore it is a bit slower but you do not have to code a byte and you get a well tested solution so it sounds quite good!

Comment: ooor, just a `std::map` + an iterator to the end.  `boost::bimap` is probably overkill

Comment: @Csq I do need to remove elements frequently. In fact, I am gonna remove the element with max Value from top of max heap. therefore, I don't think your solution work for me. What do you think ?

Comment: @MooingDuck Why it is overkill ?

Comment: @MooingDuck: An iterator to the end gives you the element with the largest *key*, not the largest *value* as requested by the OP.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe That is right !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. So it is clear that you want to use it for some get-the-maximum-values-in-an-iteration construction.

*Question 1:* Do you access the elements by their **keys** as well?

- If **yes**, I can think of two solutions for you:

  1. use `boost::bimap` - easy, tested solution with logarithmic runtimes.
  2. create a custom container that contains an `std::map` (or for even faster by key access `std::unordered_map`) and a heap implementation (e.g. `std::priority_queue<std::map<key, value>::iterator>` + custom comparator) as well, keeps them in sync, etc. This is the hard way, but maybe faster. Most operations on both will be O(logn) (insert, get&pop max, get by key, remove) but the constant sometimes do matter. Although is you use `std::unordered_map` the access by key operation will be O(1).

     You may want to write tests for the new container as well and optimize it for the operation you use the most.
- If **no**, you really just access using elements using the maximum value

  *Question 2:* do you insert/remove/update elements randomly or you first put in all elements in one round and then remove them one by one?

  - for random insert/remove/updates use `std::priority_queue<std::pair<value, key>>`
  - if you put in the elements first, and then remove them one-by-one, use and `std::vector<std::pair<value, key>>` and `std::sort()` it before the first remove operation. Do not actually remove the elements, just iterate on them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I do need to access elements by their keys. Therefore, your boost::bimap solution is good for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could build this using a `std::map` and a `std::set`.

1. One map to hold the actual values, i.e. `std::map<key, value> m;`. This is where your values are stored. Inserting elements into a map is O(log n).
2. A set of iterators pointing into the map; this set is sorted by the value of the respective map entry, i.e. `std::set<std::map<key, value>::iterator, CompareBySecondField> s;` with something like (untested):

   ```
   template <class It>
   struct CompareBySecondField : std::binary_function<It, It, bool> {
       bool operator() ( const T &lhs, const T &rhs ) const {
           return lhs->second > rhs->second;
       }
   };
   ```

   You can then get an iterator to the map entry with the largest value using `*s.begin();`.

This is rather easy to build, but you have to make sure to update both containers whenever you add/remove elements.